# AngularJS select and deselect checkboxes/radiobuttons

Tags: angularjs

I have the following example (jsFiddle). What I will do is, if radiobuttons are clicked than all checkboxes should be deselected and if one or more checkboxes are clicked than all radiobuttons should be deselected.
My question now would be how to make this (in a simple way).

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.select = function(type) {
    alert('type: ' + type);
}

// functions to deselect checkboxes if a radiobutton is selected and vica verse
}]);
```

thanks a lot for help!

[My Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zz5z6dor/5/)

Comment: You should use ng-model to bind your input elements to variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little bit late to answer your question. I think this is what you are looking for.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/bx79afyq/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <input type="radio" name="test1" ng-click="select('radio')"/>
                <span class="username">
                    Alle von Test1
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <input type="radio" name="test1" ng-click="select('radio')"/>
                <span class="username">
                    Alle von Test2
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>   

        <input type="checkbox" value="Test3" ng-click="select('checkbox')" />Test3<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="Test4" ng-click="select('checkbox')" />Test4<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="Test5" ng-click="select('checkbox')" />Test5<br />

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.select = function(type) {
       var data = angular.element('input');
       if(type==='radio'){
          angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            if(value.type==='checkbox' && angular.element(value).prop("checked")){
               angular.element(value).prop("checked", false);
             } 
          });
        }

        else if(type==='checkbox'){
           angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
              if(value.type==='radio' && angular.element(value).prop("checked")){
               angular.element(value).prop("checked", false);
              }  
           });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - thats exactly what I need!!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest using `ng-checked` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zz5z6dor/5/).

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <input type="radio" name="test1" ng-checked="radio" ng-click="selectRadio()"/>
                <span class="username">
                    Alle von Test1
                </span>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <input type="radio" name="test1" ng-checked="radio" ng-click="selectRadio()"/>
                <span class="username">
                    Alle von Test2
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>   

        <input type="checkbox" value="Test3" ng-checked="check" ng-click="selectCheck()" />Test3<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="Test4" ng-checked="check" ng-click="selectCheck()" />Test4<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="Test5" ng-checked="check" ng-click="selectCheck()" />Test5<br />

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In documentation there is a mention that shouldn't be used with ng-models. But solution seems simplest.

Comment: @guramidev Agreed. But this is just a suggestion how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using models for your inputs in your JavaScript like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        this.radioBtns = {
            test1: false,
            test2: false
        }
        this.checkboxBtns = {
            test3: false,
            test4: false,
            test5: false
        }

        this.deselect = function(type) {

            angular.forEach( this[ type ], function( el,name ) {

                this[ type ][ name ] = false;

            }.bind(this));

        }
}]);
```

And after that adjust html accordingly as shown in the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zz5z6dor/11/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example - it works fine. I would have just one further small question. Is it possible to deselect the checkboxes or radiobuttons also with the attributes  **type="radio or checkbox" name="{{institutionUserConnectionContent.institution.id}}"** - name and type because I do not have an attribute ng-model? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one more short question: I have more than one "radiobuttons - checkboxes- container". Is it possible by angular to get inputs by type **and by name** of input element:  **function select(type, name) {
            var data = angular.element('input');** Thanks a lot!